# Managed COM server and COM client do not work together

Tags: c#, com

I wrote a managed COM server and COM client in C#. When attempting to get a reference to a COM server from a COM client by using this code.

```
Type comType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("My.ComServer", true);
object comObj = Activator.CreateInstance(comType);
var comServer = (ComServer)comObj;
```

I get a reference to the new object instead of a reference to a registered server. To register a COM server I am using this code.

```
new RegistrationServices().RegisterTypeForComClients(
            typeof(ComServer),
            RegistrationClassContext.RemoteServer | RegistrationClassContext.LocalServer | RegistrationClassContext.InProcessServer,
            RegistrationConnectionType.MultipleUse);
```

P.S. When I use VB6 client everything works fine. The problem occurs with C # client.
As I understand this code does not request a reference to the current object in windows, but simply creates a new object. What to replace this code

```
Type comType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("My.ComServer", true);
object comObj = Activator.CreateInstance(comType);
var comServer = (ComServer)comObj;
```

to get a reference to a registered COM server?

Comment: This is all entirely normal.  The phrase "existing COM server" is very confusing, maybe you meant "existing COM object".  But then it is completely unclear what you did to publish the existence of that object.  Show us the code that puts it in the ROT.

Comment: For registration in ROT, I use this code, and I make a singleton inside ComServer 

new RegistrationServices().RegisterTypeForComClients(typeof(ComServer), RegistrationClassContext.RemoteServer | RegistrationClassContext.LocalServer | RegistrationClassContext.InProcessServer,  RegistrationConnectionType.MultipleUse);

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/LIBRary/system.runtime.interopservices.registrationservices.registertypeforcomclients%28v=vs.80%29

Comment: Okay, I see where's that's heading.  That call is normally made by an out-of-process server, an EXE.  A scenario that's poorly supported in .NET but was popular in VB6.  Do you actually have such an EXE running and expect the client to connect to it?  Or do you expect the client to start it?

Comment: Yes I start the Com server and wait for a connection from a Com client. If I use a com client in VB6 everything works fine, but when to this server I try to connect from C# client, C# client creates a new instance of the com server and already running server does not get commands from Com client.

Comment: The client will have to use CoGetClassObject().  Instead of the normal CoCreateInstance(), what you are using now.   Not wrapped by .NET, google "c# pinvoke cogetclassobject" to find the proper incantations.

Comment: Thank you very much for advice. Everything works fine, but I have one question. How can I use the events in C# client? I attached a small demo application.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_irffxq3qZqWEJMTGJHZWhZWTA/view?usp=sharing